# How to prevent android studio from hot reload when changing window?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, hot-reload

I am using Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 & Flutter 2.5.1 • channel stable.

Lately, when I make any change in the code and switch to the emulator or any other window it hot reloads by itself, **is there a way to disable it?** I only want to do it when I need to (using Ctrl+S for example).

It is really frustrating as it changes the state and UI even if deleted a comment or any other small change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To disable "Save files when switching to a different application" go to: File -> Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System settings -> "Save files when switching to a different application" from Autosave section.

Comment: It worked, thank you!

Comment: In Android Studio Bumblebee - This option in Preferences -> Appearance & Behavior -> System settings -> "Save files when switching to a different application" from Autosave section.